# Rcpp for library with exit(1) calls

Tags: c++, memory-management, rcpp

I've got a mixed C [cblas] / C++ [library code] library (developed by someone else) that I have wrapped in Rcpp.

Many methods have code like the one below:

```
void myclass::calculate() {
    double* dataSums = (double*) calloc(N, sizeof(double));
    if(dataSums == NULL) { printf("Memory allocation failed!\n"); exit(1); }

    // do some calculations ...
    cblas_dgemm(...);
    free(dataSums); dataSums = NULL;
}
```

Of course, the `exit(1)` is a problem here: when called from R, it shuts R down as well, which is what I don't want.

What is the best way to make sure that:

- R does not shut down when an error occurs (replace `exit` calls with exceptions?)
- memory is properly cleaned up after
- cblas stays as performant as possible (is it a problem to use `std::vector`s?)
- minimal changes to the library so it's easier to update from upstream

Comment: Ugh. Mind you, some CBLAS implementations (e.g. OpenBLAS) will also `exit`/`abort`/segfault when they're out of memory, so solving this properly may be harder than you think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest something like

```
if (dataSums == NULL)  Rcpp::stop("Memory allocation failed!\n");
```

You have the corresponding (C++) layer of `try / catch` wrapped around your code anyway
if you use Rcpp attributes, or inline, or when you do it by hand following the examples we have provided over the years.  And given the C++ exception layer, you can just use it.

If your code layer needs extra cleanup, you may add that layer there. But C++ data structures will be unwound properly.